# Software based calculator that can handle millions of digits

Tags: math, calculator

Is there a cheap or free software-based calculator that is capable of doing basic arithmetic with numbers that have millions of digits? It would be even better if you could input and output numbers in scientific notation. Also I'm not really experienced with coding, not sure if that will be relevant.

Comment: Just a clarification, you are actually referring to a million digits and not numbers, correct?

Comment: Yes, as in a single number that has a value of over one million. For example 1.9560x10^1,834,097. Thats the exact number that I want to do some problems with.

Comment: I highly doubt you need a million digits of precision.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using your browser and the Internet, [**Wolfram Alpha**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) is a good choice. It's free to use and handles [arbitrary-precision numbers](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/numbers/arbitrary-precision/).

Answer (score 2):

KBH Thousand Digit Op will multiply one-thousand digit numbers and will divide two-thousand digit numbers.

Otherwise, there are numerical libraries for the Unix and Linux C compiler. And the Unix and Linux C compiler has been ported to Windows. Also, there are numerical libraries for Python.

Comment: Are you the author of this program? If yes, please disclose it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Julia](https://julialang.org/) can handle arbitrary numbers and is available for many platforms.

> julia> # multiply a big number by two in julia:
>
> julia> 1.9560*10^big(1834097) * 2

Answer (score 0):

[GNU dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html) but it has command-line interface.
Some [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_%28computer_program%29#Basic_operations) in Wikipedia.